# how to use auth in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

i need to use the auth to auth the user to do a few thing and to get their id to be assign to the database but the controller seems to cant get the auth::user
the code is like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Job;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreJobRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateJobRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
     public function insert(Request $request) {
            // Validate the request data
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required|max:255',
            'jenis' => 'required|in:full-time,part-time,freelance',
            'gaji' => 'required|numeric',
        ]);

        // Create a new job post with the validated data
        $job = new Job;
        $job->name = $validatedData['name'];
        $job->detail = $validatedData['detail'];
        $job->address = $validatedData['address'];
        $job->gaji = $validatedData['gaji'];
        $job->jenis = $validatedData['jenis'];
        $job->user_id = Auth::user()->id; // Get the ID of the authenticated user
        $job->save();
        if ($job) {
            Alert::success('Success', 'anda berhasil mendaftarkan lowongan');
            return redirect()->route('jobs.search');
            
        }
        else {
            Alert::error('Failed', 'gagal meregristrasi');
            return back();
        }
```

how do i solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... "the controller seems to cant get the `auth::user`": is there an error? what is happening instead of what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

to

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Here you can read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user).